# How to see a given hour traffic in Awstats?

Tags: awstats

I have installed and configure Awstats on my server to see its traffic.

How can I see the traffic of a given hour of a given day in Awstats? I need to know who visited what pages in 23 PM of the 13/Dec .

Comment: I don't think you can in Awstats. For any one day you seem to only be able to access the total number of... "visits", "pages", "hits" and "bandwidth".

Comment: So what can I use for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these, Enjoy ;)

1. [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)
2. [Woopra](http://www.woopra.com/)
3. [Mint](http://haveamint.com/)
4. [Clicky](http://imimpact.com/getclicky)
5. [StatCounter](http://statcounter.com/)
6. [Reinvigorate](http://www.reinvigorate.net/)
7. [Piwik](http://piwik.org/)
8. [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com)
9. [Chart Beat](http://chartbeat.com)
10. [Mixpanel](http://mixpanel.com)
11. [Kiss Metrics](http://www.kissmetrics.com/)
12. [Fox Metrics](http://foxmetrics.com/)
13. [Going Up](http://www.goingup.com/)
14. [Engine Ready](http://www.engineready.com/)
15. [Stuffed Tracker](http://www.stuffedtracker.com/)